# How to put a tikzpicture shapes in specific position

Tags: latex, beamer

My question is how we can put a tikzpicture shapes in specific position in latex slides? I mean I do not want to change the position of texts in slide but draw a shape in a specific position. (like powerpoint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `overlay` option, your tikz picture won't influence the rest of the text:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

% trick taken from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989
\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  some text, does not change position
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \fill[red] (0.7,0.3) circle [radius=0.5cm];
  \end{tikzpicture}%

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```